# Backbone Validate is sending a request when validation fails

Tags: validation, backbone.js

According to the backbone documentation about validation it states:

> If validate returns an error, set and save will not continue, and the
>   model attributes will not be modified.

So the way I read that set or save should never run if the validation fails. But that is not the results I am getting. Even when validation fails it still sends the POST/PUT request. Am I reading the docs wrong or doing something incorrect in my code?

Here is my relevant code:
https://gist.github.com/80f6ef0099fbe96025dc

```
App.Models.Test = Backbone.Model.extend(
    urlRoot: '/api/test'

    validate: (attrs) ->
        errors = []
        if attrs.to is ''
            errors.push
                name: "to"
                field: "js-to"
                message: "You must enter a to address"
        if attrs.subject is ''
            errors.push
                name: "subject"
                field: "js-subject"
                message: "You must enter a subject"

        # Return our errors array if it isn't empty
        errors  if errors.length > 0
)

App.Views.Details = Backbone.View.extend(
    initialize: ->
        @model.bind "error", @error, this

    events:
        "click #js-save": "saveItem"

    saveItem: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()

        # Set the model then save it.
        @model.set
            subject: $("#js-subject").val()
            message: $("#js-message").val()
            mailbox_id: $("#js-from").val()
            to: $("#js-to").val()
            cc: $("#js-cc").val()
            bcc: $("#js-bcc").val()
            tags: App.Helpers.tagsToObject $('#js-tags').val()
            scope: $('#js-scope').val()
            attachments: attachments

        @model.save null,
            success: (model, response) =>
                App.Helpers.showAlert "Success!", "Saved Successfully", "alert-success"
                @next()
            error: (model, response) ->
                App.Helpers.showAlert "Error", "An error occurred while trying to save this item", "alert-error"

    # Show the errors based on validation failure.
    error: (model, error) ->
        App.Helpers.displayValidationErrors error
```

Comment: I think this could be easily fixed in the documentation. Only set triggers validation. And if the save is supplied with attributes, it will also trigger save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this to save your model:

```
@model.save null,
    success: -> ...
    error:   -> ...
```

That `null` is the source of your trouble, use `{}` and things will start behaving better; if you combine your `@model.set` and `@model.save` calls, things will be even better:

```
attrs =
    subject: $("#js-subject").val()
    #...
@model.save attrs,
    success: -> ...
    error:   -> ...
```

A [`save`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save) call looks like this:

> **save** `model.save([attributes], [options])`
>   [...]
>   The **attributes** hash (as in `set`) should contain the attributes you'd like to change

So passing a `null` for `attributes` means that you want to save the model as it is.

When you [`save`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save) a model, the validation is mostly left up to [`set`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set), the [code looks like this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L360):

```
if (attrs && !this.set(attrs, options.wait ? silentOptions : options)) {
  return false;
}
```

Your `attrs` will be `null` so `set` will not be called; however, if you let `save` handle your `set`, you will get the behavior you're after. If you passed the `wait: true` option, `save` would [manually run the validation](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L353) on the passed attributes:

```
if (options.wait) {
  if (!this._validate(attrs, options)) return false;
  ...
}
```

The internal [`_validate`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L524) method is a wrapper for `validate` that does some bookkeeping and error handling. You're not using `wait: true` so this doesn't apply to you but I thought it was worth mentioning anyway.

Consider a simple example with a model whose `validate` always fails. If you say this:

```
@model.on 'error', @error
@model.save attrs,
    success: -> console.log 'AJAX success'
    error:   -> console.log 'AJAX error'
```

then `@error` will be called because `save` will end up calling `set` with [some attributes](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L343) and `set` will call `validate`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HHQ2N/1/

But, if you say:

```
@model.save null, ...
```

the `null` [will cause the `set` call to be skipped](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L360). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6pX2e/ (the AJAX here will fail).

Your `@model.set` call right before `@model.save` should be triggering your error handler but if you don't check what `@model.set` returns, execution will blindly continue on to the `save` call and talk to your server.

---

In summary, you have three things going on here:

1. You're not calling `save` they way you should be.
2. You're ignoring the `@model.set` return value and losing your chance to trap the validation errors.
3. Backbone's argument handling for `save(null, ...)` could be better but I don't know if it is worth the effort to handle a strange way of calling it.

You should combine your `set`/`save` pair into just a `save` or check what `set` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is now working by testing that set returns before saving.  I was not able to remove the null from save or my callbacks wouldn't fire.  Probably another issue but I seen this in regards to that: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547430/backbone-js-save-with-coffeescript

Comment: @Eric: Sorry, I ended up running off on the *wrong* tangent. Your best bet is to just use `@model.save attrs, ...` and don't bother with a separate `set` call. Give my updated answer a read.